# Why are these variables of an interface type not being used to instantiate new objects?

Tags: java

I'm using [this](http://javadoc.jlibav.googlecode.com/git/index.html) api and have come across some a code example that is confusing me. I know that I can assign an object to an interface using "new", since an interface is a datatype. What I don't understand from the code below is why the variables: "cc" and "audioDecoder" are assigned the values that they have been assigned. As far as I know, those variables should be assigned to new objects. Could someone explain what is going on here?

```
try {
// open media file 
DefaultMediaPlayer player = new DefaultMediaPlayer("/home/me/walking.wav");

// get some properties of the first audio stream 
IDecoder audioDecoder = player.getAudioStreamDecoder(0);
ICodecContextWrapper cc = audioDecoder.getCodecContext();

int sampleFormat = cc.getSampleFormat();
int sampleRate = cc.getSampleRate();
int bytesPerSample = AVSampleFormat.getBytesPerSample(sampleFormat);
long channelLayout = cc.getChannelLayout();
int channelCount = AVChannelLayout.getChannelCount(channelLayout);
AudioFormat.Encoding encoding;

if (AVSampleFormat.isPlanar(sampleFormat) || AVSampleFormat.isReal(sampleFormat))
    throw new LibavException("unsupported output sample format");
else if (AVSampleFormat.isSigned(sampleFormat))
    encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED;
else
    encoding = AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_UNSIGNED;

// create Java InputStream for audio stream raw data
SampleInputStream sis = new SampleInputStream(sampleRate * bytesPerSample * channelCount, true);

// create AudioInputStream from the SampleInputStream
AudioInputStream audioStream = new AudioInputStream(sis, new AudioFormat(encoding, sampleRate,
    bytesPerSample * 8, channelCount, bytesPerSample * channelCount, sampleRate, 
    ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN.equals(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())), -1);

// create adapter between Libav audio frames and the SampleInputStream
Frame2AudioFrameAdapter resampler = new Frame2AudioFrameAdapter(channelLayout, channelLayout, sampleRate, 
    sampleRate, sampleFormat, sampleFormat);

// get audio mixer for the audio stream format
PlaybackMixer audioMixer = PlaybackMixer.getMixer(audioStream.getFormat());

// connect all streams
audioDecoder.addFrameConsumer(resampler);
resampler.addAudioFrameConsumer(sis);
audioMixer.addInputStream(audioStream); 

// enable audio stream decoding
player.setAudioStreamDecodingEnabled(0, true);

// start playback
audioMixer.play();
player.play();

// wait until the playback stops
player.join();

// release system resources
player.close();
resampler.dispose();
PlaybackMixer.closeAllMixers();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(PlaybackSample.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "unable to play audio", ex);
}
```

Comment: Your question confuses me as I don't understand what about the code above confuses you. cc and audioDecoder appear to be assigned to legitimate objects. Point of clarification: You cannot create a `new SomeInterface()` object since a naked interface has no implementation. The only way to do this is with an anonymous inner class created from the interface.

Comment: I'm a little lost too--the results of those calls are being assigned to valid references; what's the issue? Variables don't need to be assigned new objects, just objects: `Foo foo = new Foo(); Foo foo2 = foo;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have gone through the API document. The method [DefaultMediaPlayer.getAudioStreamDecoder](http://javadoc.jlibav.googlecode.com/git/index.html)

is returning the instance of type *IDecoder*. Thats why in the src they are assigning the return type to *audioDecoder* variable of type *IDecoder*.

```
// get some properties of the first audio stream 
IDecoder audioDecoder = player.getAudioStreamDecoder(0);
ICodecContextWrapper cc = audioDecoder.getCodecContext();
```

There is no rule saying that you can assign objects to Interface type only using `new`. You can assign object instances from method return types.

Likewise the method `IDecoder.getCodecContext()` returns the object of instance `ICodecContextWrapper` which is being assigned to variable `cc`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create the object all the time like this

```
SomeClass obj=new SomeClass();
```

you can have some case like this

```
public class OtherClass
{
  public SomeClass getSomeClassObject()
 {
    return new SomeClass();
 }
}
```

`given that SomeClass is accesible within OtherClass`

you can use it as below

```
OtherClass other=new OtherClass();
SomeClass come=other.getSomeClassObject();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ICodecContextWrapper cc = audioDecoder.getCodecContext();
```

the getCodecContext is probably something like this:

```
ICodecContextWrapper getCodecContext() {

return new ICodecContextWrapper() {
  //override methods
};

}
```