# How can an interface be used without the keyword "implements"?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are these variables of an interface type not being used to instantiate new objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132849/why-are-these-variables-of-an-interface-type-not-being-used-to-instantiate-new-o)

In the code sample below from an [API](http://javadoc.jlibav.googlecode.com/git/index.html) that I'm using, there is an initialization of the variables, "audiodecoder" and "cc". The two variables are of an interface type. However, the keyword **implements** is not used anywhere in the code sample for any thing but actionlisteners.

This goes against anything I've learned about Java so far. I've listed the import statements below in the thinking that maybe they hold some clue about why IDecoder and ICodecContextWrapper do not have corresponding **implements** statements. I've also tried to find some documentation on using interfaces in this manner with no success. Could someone explain to me why the keyword **implements** is not used? Is there a name for this  concept and, perhaps some documentation that you know of in regards to the concept?

edit: I should also add that the variables are not declared in the sample code with the keyword **new** either.

```
import org.libav.audio.Frame2AudioFrameAdapter;
import org.libav.audio.PlaybackMixer;
import org.libav.audio.SampleInputStream;
import org.libav.avcodec.ICodecContextWrapper;
import org.libav.avformat.IChapterWrapper;
import org.libav.avformat.IFormatContextWrapper;
import org.libav.avformat.IStreamWrapper;
import org.libav.avresample.bridge.AVResampleLibrary;
import org.libav.avutil.IDictionaryWrapper;
import org.libav.avutil.bridge.AVChannelLayout;
import org.libav.avutil.bridge.AVSampleFormat;
import org.libav.bridge.LibraryManager;
import org.libav.data.IFrameConsumer;
import org.libav.util.swing.VideoPane;


IDecoder audioDecoder = player.getAudioStreamDecoder(streamIndex);
ICodecContextWrapper cc = audioDecoder.getCodecContext();
```

Comment: This was already answered in your previous question. The objects created by the player and audioDecoder implement the interface. If you check the source code if it were available to you, you'd see this.

Comment: what is the return type of `player.getAudioStreamDecoder(streamIndex)`?

Comment: just think of `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`. `List` also is an interface.

Comment: No it wasn't, hovercraft and cory. I'd like to get an in depth explanation and perhaps a name for the concept.

Comment: @user465001 I have to agree with Hovercraft Full Of Eels. I read the question and answer. The name of the concept is **polymorphism**.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This

```
IDecoder audioDecoder = player.getAudioStreamDecoder(streamIndex);
```

means that whatever is returned *implements* `IDecoder`.

e.g.

```
public IDecoder getAudioStreamDecoder() {
   // constructs...
   return new IDecoderImplementation(); 
}
```

Note the distinction in types between what's constructed, and the returned reference.

The object returned will be a concrete class, but since it implements that interface, it can be referred to by that interface. It *could* implement other interfaces too, and could have functionality exposed, but you'll only be able to access it as a `IDecoder`

Comment: player is created like so: **DefaultMediaPlayer player = new DefaultMediaPlayer** and DefaulMediaPlayer has method **public IDecoder getAudioStreamDecoder()** with a return type of, what I thought was just an interface, **Idecoder**. How does **public IDecoder getAudioStreamDecoder()** return a concrete class when IDecoder is supposed to be an interface?

Comment: @user465001: When the return type of a method is an interface, it just means that it can return *any* class that implements `IDecoder`. You are technically working with a concrete class but you only have access to the methods/properties defined in that interface. This is the nature of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). The idea is that you aren't limited to a single implementation, nor do you need to know the implementation details. The proper `IDecoder` implementation is returned to you based on context likely with the use of the Factory pattern.

Comment: @Cory: Hi Cory. Thanks for taking the time to help me out. I understand a little about polymorphism but, the syntax in this project has added to my confusion. Your help has been very valuable in clearing up some of that confusion.

Comment: @user465001: Glad I could help. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

#### Just some FYI:

According to the [jlibav API documentation](http://javadoc.jlibav.googlecode.com/git/index.html), there are two classes that are concrete implementations of `IDecoder`:

- `AudioFrameDecoder` and
- `VideoFrameDecoder`

Your `IDecoder` is an instance of one of those two classes. `IDecoder` also extends two other interfaces:

- `IFrameProducer` and
- `IPacketConsumer`

The same goes for the `ICodecContextWrapper`. There are three known classes that implement that interface:

- `AbstractCodecContextWrapper`,
- `CodecContextWrapper53`, and
- `CodecContextWrapper54`

Your `ICodecContextWrapper` is an instance of one of those three.

This concept is called [**polymorphism**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). If it's confusing (and it very well may be for a beginner), you may wish to pick up some study material.